# How to add log4j.properties and log4j.jar to executable jar..?

Tags: java, jar, log4j

I have following folder structure...

```
MyApp
      |com
      |lib
          |--- log4j-1.2.17.jar,mysqlconn.jar,jcalendar-1.4.jar,poi-3.9.jar
      |prop
          |---log4j.properties
      |manifest.txt
```

manifest.txt :

```
 Main-Class: com.java.test.WelcomeScreen
 Class-Path: prop lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar lib/poi-3.9.jar
```

I am creating executable jar as follow :

```
 C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyApp>jar -cvfm myapp.jar manifest.txt com/java/test/*.class com/java/db/*.class
```

And then running:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyApp>java -jar myapp.jar
```

I am getting following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
        at com.java.test.LoginForm.<clinit>(LoginForm.java:17)
        at com.java.test.WelcomeScreen.main(WelcomeScreen.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

Comment: Shouldnt manifest contain `log4j-1.2.15.jar` instead of `log4j-1.2.17.jar`?

Comment: sorry it was typo mistake

Comment: do I need to give "prop/log4.properties" instead of "prop" in manifest.txt..?

Comment: Add an empty line at the end of your manifest and try again. `prop` seems fine to me as you are adding that directory to the classpath

Comment: ohhh I added empty line in manifest.txt it work now but it does not finding log4.properties file giving "log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly."

Comment: I solved I added backslash to "prop/" its work now thank you....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an empty line at the end of your manifest.
Also just including the directory is fine where your `log4j.properties` exists. 
I was going to suggest putting the log4.properties in the same path as your main jar file and adding "." to the Class-Path. But looks like adding a `/` to the end of the directory works as found by OP.

Comment: can I store absolute path of jar files and log4.properties in manifest.txt so that excutable jar file can be kept anywhere and user will just double click to launch there applicatiton?